# Fundamental group of wedge sum not equal to the free product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Wedge sum's Wikipedia article states that:

"Van Kampen's theorem gives certain conditions (which are usually fulfilled for well-behaved spaces, such as CW complexes) under which the fundamental group of the wedge sum of two spaces X and Y is the free product of the fundamental groups of X and Y."

Is there a counterexample to the general statement, for path-connected spaces?

Namely - two path-connected topological spaces $X, Y$ such that $\pi_1(X \vee Y) \ne \pi_1(X)\ *\ \pi_1(Y)$

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760254/fundamental-group-of-a-wedge-sum-in-general-e-g-when-van-kampen-does-not-appl).

Comment: I saw this post. Correct me if I'm wrong  - they don't give any example for path-connected X,Y (editing the post now, because I forgot to mention that non-path-connected spaces don't interest me.)

Comment: The Van Kampen theorem says essentially that the wedging point of each space needs a simply connected neighborhood, doesn't it? Then that tells you exactly where to look for counterexamples. The given answer below is the immediate first thing to try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Observe that the Hawaiian Earrings ${\mathbb H}$ is homeomorphic to ${\mathbb H}\vee {\mathbb H}$. On the otber hand, it is proven by Sam Corson (see the answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353241/free-product-decompositions-of-the-fundamental-group-of-hawaiian-earrings)) that if $G=\pi_1({\mathbb H})\cong G_1\star G_2$, then one of the free factors is finitely generated. Since $G$ is not finitely generated, you get your example.

Edit. Incidentally, it is a nice exercise to find example of a loop in ${\mathbb H}$ which is not homotopic to a (finite) product of loops contained the summands of the wedge sum decomposition ${\mathbb H}\vee {\mathbb H}$.

Comment: Assuming they are wedged at the singularity.

Comment: @Arthur Of course.

Comment: Also cone over $H$ gives a nice example because wedge of two cones isn't simply connected.

Comment: @KoppeKToP: Right, but depending on the point where the wedge is made.